# Gdbserver exits on start and causes hangs

Tags: android, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug an ARMv7 Android app .so with gdbserver. I've downloaded the android NDK for Mac and and pushed the gdbserver located at `prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver` to the machine. I'm using Nox App Player v3.0 Mac version.

When attaching to the process, it produces this output:

```
$ adb shell gdbserver :5055 --attach 2289
Attached; pid = 2289
ptrace(regsets_fetch_inferior_registers) PID=4034: Device or resource busy
ptrace(regsets_fetch_inferior_registers) PID=4034: Function not implemented
ptrace(regsets_fetch_inferior_registers) PID=4034: Function not implemented
Warning: ptrace(regsets_store_inferior_registers): Device or resource busy
Warning: ptrace(regsets_store_inferior_registers): Function not implemented
Warning: ptrace(regsets_store_inferior_registers): Function not implemented
writing register 0: Function not implemented
Exiting
```

The app I tried to attach to then hangs. The rest of the emulator/phone works, and I can use the home and menu buttons to close the app. It's just the app that it tried to attach to that stops working until I restart it. I can attach to other random process numbers, even if it does complain a bit about it. Apps have this problem even if I attach while they are suspended. Checking the /data/data/ folder for the application shows that the .so the running app is using is ARMv7.

I tried using the `prebuilt/android-x86/gdbserver/gdbserver` version of gdbserver to see what would happen. This version loads the process fine with no hangs, and I can connect to it with the GDB the NDK provides. Of course, this also means I can't load the .so, because the gdbserver version is x86 instead of ARM. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can compile the `gdbserver` for your target machine.

You can type `uname -m` for checking platform.